How can you open a Google Form that is closed without the owner account?
I was too late for a statistics quiz. How can you open a Google Form that is closed without the owner account?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If the form is no longer accepting responses, you will have to ask the form owner or another person who has edit access to the form to re-open it in order to submit another response.
